# IsAdministrator check no longer working on Sitecore 9.1

Tags: security, identity-server

I created a few pages within our Sitecore setup to be accessed only by the Sitecore administrator while our site was still running on 8.2, using

`Sitecore.Context.IsAdministrator`

to check if the user was an administrator or not on the controller level.
After upgrading to Sitecore 9.1 the same line of code does not work anymore and is always returning false due to the user now being seen as

`extranet\anonymous`

Is there any way I can get the correct logged in user? as I suspect this has something to do with identityserver.

Edit: these pages are like Sitecore admin pages, but instead of creating aspx pages and storing them under the sitecore\admin folder in the webroot, they are Sitecore items built using MVC and are saved under the main Sitecore tree.

The process into navigating to them would be like this:

1- Sitecore admin log's into Sitecore

2- Sitecore admin navigates to the following URL:
https://hostname/securepages/mysecurepage

and can view the page.

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.User.Name` 100% still works in 9.1 for a normal login via `AuthenticationManager.Login(accountName, password, rememberMe);`

Comment: I'm not logging into these pages, I'm a sitecore admin who is already logged in and then navigates to these pages, which are within the tree of the main site under the home item

Comment: So you are trying to use this code while in the Sitecore Content Editor?

Comment: while logged in, but not from the content editor, I added a few edits to the original question to add more detail to the flow

Comment: Here is an image of 9.1 logged in as admin. https://www.screencast.com/t/LAtsvqzdf8Cx You are for sure in the same browser session as the logged in user?

Comment: Yes, I tried accessing the page from the same browser window I logged on to as well but without luck

Comment: Definitely some funk with Identity Server. The following was required for the Unicorn Control Panel. https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.UI.IdentityServer.config.disabled  Wasn't me who came up with this however, so I'm not 100% up to speed of why this works and what it does to Identity Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 9.1, you need to patch in the path of your custom admin pages to the list of the `siteNeutralPaths` for the `ValidateSiteNeutralPaths` processor in the `owin.cookieAuthentication.validateIdentity` pipeline like so:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.validateIdentity>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.ValidateIdentity.ValidateSiteNeutralPaths, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <siteNeutralPaths hint="list">
            <!-- You could get as specific as /securepages/mysecurepage for the path if you don't have any other pages under the /securepages path. -->
            <path hint="securepages">/securepages</path>
          </siteNeutralPaths>
        </processor>
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.validateIdentity>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

If you look at the `ValidateSiteNeutralPaths` processor on `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`, Sitecore has provided an explanation for why this is needed (taken from 9.1 Initial Release):

> There are scenarios when some URIs are resolved with the `website` context, but should be executed within the `shell` context instead.
>
> Example: `/sitecore/api/ssc/ListManagement/List/Recent?pageSize=6&pageIndex=1&payLoad=full&language=en&searchExpression=&sc_lang=en`
>
> If an external identity provider is configured to only be used with the `shell` site, we must be able to use a user from that provider to make the authorized request. Use this processor to specify these paths.
>
> Note: if you need to omit the execution of this processor for some URIs (e.x. for API requests from website on CM), add the `sc_site=...` query parameter to the requested URI.

Comment: Is there any reason this would not work? I am doing this similarly for Unicorn and have the patch installed for the `/unicorn.aspx` URL, but am still allowed to browse to it anonymously.