# How to check access right in SitecoreController for Sitecore 9.1

Tags: security, sitecore-api, controller

In my JSON controller I want to check the access right from the User.

My code looks like this

```
public class MyController : SitecoreController
{

    public static bool CheckAccessRight()
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole("sitecore\\Sitecore Client Users"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet, System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoSomethings(int page)
    {
      if (!CheckAccessRight())
      {
        return new JsonResult { Data = "access denied", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
      }
      return new JsonResult { Data = "my data", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

The controller is registered in the initialize Pipeline. simiar to the documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-mvc-routing.html. Works on older versions of Sitecore but in Sitecore 9.1 update-1 the `Sitecore.Context.User` gives not the logged in user but gives 
 `extranet\Anonymous`

How can I get the actual user back?

Note: it fails in Sitecore 9.1 initial version and Sitecore 9.1 update-1. works on 9.0

Comment: You might find this useful: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17485/237

Comment: Thank @Gatogordo it works when I add ?sc_site=shell to the Url, I had already try it with the siteSwitcher to shell but that fails.

Comment: Does this fail for GET and POST calls?

Comment: Post and GET fail, but for me it resolved with adding shell to the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `?sc_site=shell` to the url, in the shell context the Sitecore user will be correct.

See also [IsAdministrator check no longer working on Sitecore 9.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17485/isadministrator-check-no-longer-working-on-sitecore-9-1)